# PIP for Python3 installs Python2 script that cannot be ran

Tags: python, windows, pip, miniconda

I've installed a small script `ever2simple` via pip as follows: `pip install -U ever2simple` (following the [installation instructions](https://github.com/dougdiego/ever2simple))

It has installed an `EXE` file to `...\Miniconda3\Scripts\ever2simple.exe` (I use Miniconda3 64bit for Python 3.6 on Windows 10 x64). When I try to run this, it gives me

`SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(print 'File does not exist: %s' % filepath)?`

Looks like this is because script is for Python2. How do I make the script working on my machine? Isn't this bug in pip, as it allows to install Python2 script that cannot be properly ran?

Thanks!

Comment: The last update of `ever2simple` was on 2016-05-13 and *Test on Python 3* is in the to-list. So it looks as though there may not be a Python 3 version yet. As for being a bug, Pip can't tell if the code is Python 2 or Python 3 (some code is one, some is the other, and some will run under both).

Comment: Also, if you were to install a Python3 package, it should be using `pip3`, not `pip`.

Comment: @Mangu That depends on the setup. In a properly setup virtual environment and in case there is no Python 2 installed `pip` is sufficient.

Comment: @KlausD. I didn't know. Thanks for the info :)